# Ubuntu 18.04.1 takes a long time to shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, docker

My Ubuntu takes a very long time to shutdown. I see this message when I press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key and the loading screen disappears:

> A job stop is running for Docker Application Container Engine (15min 41s / no limit)

I do not know how to fix it!

Comment: Seems like you have a Docker container running. Have you voluntarily installed Docker? In any case, in a terminal, run the command 'sudo docker ps'. What do you get?

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine Yes, I've installed myself, but I didn't have any problem since the latest update of Docker. here is what the command prints:

`
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
`

Comment: so apparently, you have no container running. That's very strange. For what it's worth, I have docker installed in Ubuntu 18.04 and have no such problem. How did you install Docker?

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine I've followed the instructions which have been written on Docker official website. I found that this problem would not happen if I stop Docker service manually using `sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop`, before shutting my laptop down.